# Put a JS variable in MVC5 Url.Content()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to put a URL in an `@Url.Content("")`.

I allow the user to choose their home page in my portal (as long as they display anything unnecessary on the home page) and I put this value in a column of my User table.

As long as this column is null I display a modal to select its home page. So once the connection returns "Success", I redirect to the correct page, but I am not able to pass a variable in `@Url.Content(HERE)` with the value in my column (Example: `/Home/Index`).

Here is my code:

```js
IdentificationSucces = function(data) {
  if (@Session["SpAccueilDefaut"]) {
    var url = @Session["SpAccueilDefaut"].ToString();
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("" + url +"")';
  } else {
    window.location.href = '@Url.Content("~/Intranet/Index")';
  }
};
```

My `url` variable is in error and this is the message:

> The name'url' does not exist in the current context

Comment: If `@Session["SpAccueilDefaut"]` contains a *url* then you want just  `window.location.href = "@Session["SpAccueilDefaut"].ToString()"` (without the `var url =` part).   `@Url.Action(url)` implies the "url" is an action name, not a url

Answer (score 1):

You're defining `url` in the JS on the client side. The `Url.Action()` call happens on the server side. The two cannot directly interact in the manner you're attempting.

The workaround in this case is to provide the `Session["SpAccueilDefaut"]` value directly to the `Url.Action()` as they are both held server side.

In addition, if the value in `Session["SpAccueilDefaut"]` is a string, which appears to be the case from the context it's used in later, then you need to delimit it using quotes in the JS `if` condition:

```
IdentificationSucces = function(data) {
  if ('@Session["SpAccueilDefaut"]') {
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action(Session["SpAccueilDefaut"].ToString())';
  } else {
    window.location.href = '@Url.Content("~/Intranet/Index")';
  }
};
```

As an aside, I'd suggest you research the difference between client side and server side programming. Understanding this is vital to developing web based technologies: [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429/519413)

Comment: Thank, its work. I understand the 2nd part of your answer on understanding the difference between client side and server side. I say make a correction in the path to my project and no longer use @ Url.Action () and @ Url.Content (). (I don't have enough reputation to vote for the answer)